# Раздельное подключение библиотек для Windows и Linux в QMAKE

Tags: c++, qtcreator, qmake

Проект на C++ использует систему сборки qmake (родная для Qt). Библиотека сокетов `lws2_32` линкуется только при сборке на Windows, в *nix ее нет и она там вовсе не нужна. Встал вопрос: как задать в *.pro-файле (конфиг qmake, он же файл проекта QtCreator) дополнительную библиотеку при сборке на Windows.

Вот так собирается, но для сборки под линуксами нужно вручную убирать `lws2_32`.

```
LIBS += \
    -lcrypto \
    -lpthread \
    -lws2_32
```

Пробовал писать вот так:

```
    LIBS += \
    -lcrypto \
    -lpthread

    QMAKE_LIBS_WINDOWS += \
    -lws2_32
```

Но на той же винде библиотека не подтянулась :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочее решение:

```
win32 {
LIBS += \
    -lcrypto \
    -lpthread \
    -lws2_32
}
!win32 {
LIBS += \
    -lcrypto \
    -lpthread
}
```

Comment: Мне представляется, что повторять весь список не обязательно, достаточно сделать `win32 { LIBS += -lws2_32 }`